# What is difference between Entity Framework and web service in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I really want to know what is difference between web service and Entity Framework as I'm not getting the below requirement in an ASP.NET project.

Use .NET project (MVC or Webforms), C# & SQL Server to do the following:

1. Create a web service for all the database calls (reading & writing)
2. For all database queries use stored procedures to call them

Comment: Well, a web service is exactly that.  A service that exposes methods to the web.  Entity Framework, is an ORM (Object Relation Model) technology used for DB reading and writing

Comment: webservices like rest, soap, ect. go hand in hand with entity framework

Comment: do you have any resource for a web service that includes an entity framework, I didn't get the full concept.@Hursey @Nonik

Comment: microsoft has it well documented